in lyx: preview of ert environment inside a table cell has weird bounds compared to the compiled output
In using the latest version of LyX (2.3.7) when I insert an ERT environment inside a preview, and all of that inside a table cell the output on the lyx file takes a huge part of the page length  (I cant fit it all in the screen)

but the compiled file actually handles it correctly as you can see in the pic here 
is there a way to ensure that the preview inside the lyx document itself will also be bounded to a certain size? just for ease of readability inside the LyX document itself.
thanks in advance

Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show the used TeX code in Lyx? Then we do not have to guess what you or Lyx is doing ...

@Mensch can you explain what you mean by the TeX code in LyX? isn't that what I've provided in the second pic? and how do I access it?

I know that you can copy the complete TeX code Lyx uses. Please show us this complete, compilable TeX code. I'm not using Lyx, I can not tell you how to do it, sorry. And please never add code as image, we can not copy and test it!

@Mensch the problem is inherently in LyX in the preview environment, I'm hoping that people knowledgeable in LyX will see this and help

Two options:

Close the ERT box in the edit screen:

 x Right click on ERT box →  Close Inset ...or ...
View  → Close All Insets




Fix the width of the column with the ERT box. If the raw LaTeX code have line breaks, the ERT box will widen as far as possible. In the default columns this means that the ERT can expand as in the main text or even more, as there are not any width to attach to. If you set the width of the column, the ERT box will be narroved to represent (more or less) this width, wrapping the code if needed. But note that fix  the width to see the ERT box could have little no sense in the final PDF.


